# R Programming - Update mysql db rows where a condition is met

Tags: r

I have a data frame that is structured identical to a table in my mysql db. I want to update the rows of the mysql db where the primary key of my data frame and that table match.

For example

```
DF 1

PK Count  Temperature
3    1        111
4    2        100
5    3        190
6    4        200

MySQL Table

        PK Count  Temperature
        1    1        100
        2    10       11
        3    0        0
        4    0        0
        5    0        0
        6    0        0
        7    0        0
        8    0        0
```

Notice that I can't simply overwrite the table because I have rows in my DB that do not exist in my data frame.

After the update, what I would like to have is the following table.

```
 PK Count  Temperature
    1    1        100
    2    10       11
    3    1        111
    4    2        100
    5    3        190
    6    4        200
    7    0        0
    8    0        0
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Write your dataframe to a temp table in the DB.  Perform an update of the main table from the temp table.  Delete the temp table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I haven't been able to directly update a row. However, what I have done is create a holding table in my DB that I can append to from R. I then created a trigger in my db to update the desired rows in my desired table. From their, I have created another trigger to empty my holding table.

This is sort of what Dean was suggesting, but a little different.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I am providing alternative approach over writing frame to a temp table and performing update in the main table or getting holding table, append, and update desired table by trigger method.

I believe following approach is easy and effective as it performs update record directly in the target table.

```
#install.packages("RMySQL")
#install.packages("DBI")
library(DBI)
library(RMySQL)

#Establish the connection
mydb = dbConnect(MySQL(), 
                  user='your  user', 
                  password='your  password', 
                  dbname='your DB name', 
                 host='Host Name')
#Eusuring the connection working by listing table
dbListTables(mydb)

#Applying update statement directly
rs = dbSendQuery(mydb, "UPDATE DB_NAME.TABLE_1 
SET    FIELD_1 = 0 
                 WHERE  ID = 5")

#Verifying the result
rs = dbSendQuery(mydb, "SELECT * FROM DB_NAME.TABLE_1
                 WHERE  ID = 5")
data = fetch(rs, n=-1)
print(data)
```

I have tried above code in R Studio Version 1.1.453 and R 3.5.0 (64bit).